# Which species of iron-reducing bacteria are hyper-sensitive to copper?

Tags: microbiology, ecology

I would like to know which species of iron-reducing bacteria are inhibited in their iron metabolism by a copper concentration of less than 500 nano moles per litre.

Searching the internet, I can only find Klebsiella/Enterobacter/Aerobacter aerogenes, and I'm not even certain that that is an iron-reducing organism.
According to one reference, there are "other" iron-reducers which are similarly allergic to copper, but it doesn't mention which they might be.

I have done cultures in which iron-reduction appeared to be inhibited by a copper concentration of less than 100 nano moles per litre, and I am trying to identify the organism by a process of elimination.

Comment: Presumably these are environmental cultures? If so, work on eliminating the common ones first. You might need to do this by culture and test, though you may also be able to do it through next-gen sequencing and looking at abundance changes between with and without copper. Just because you can't find data on the internet doesn't mean that a particular species isn't inhibited, it might just be that it has never been tested.

Comment: Thank you for replying bob1.  The cultures were done in rainwater, though unfortunately I no longer have a sample of the organism.  At the time when I was doing this, I didn't know that iron reducing bacteria existed.

Comment: I don't have a list, but copper has a pretty strong antifungal and antibacterial action, at least against pathogenic species.